# Why isn't std::function working with perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

**Note:**

- I apologize in advance but I was unable to reduce/simplify the code any further (i.e., all my smaller tests couldn't reproduce this issue)
- Version 1 of the code compiles but **does not execute properly** using Visual Studio 2010 Premium
- Version 2 & 3 of the code **compiles and executes successfully** using Visual Studio 2010 Premium
- All versions of the code **compiles and executes successfully** using ideone.com (C++14)

## Version 1 Output (Visual Studio 2010)

```
Signal1<A1>::raise(7)
Slot::operator()(7)
Slot1<A1>::operator()(7)
Handling new value: 3931764 // This value changes on each execution
```

## Version 2 Output (Visual Studio 2010)

```
Signal1<A1>::raise(7)
Slot::operator()(7)
Slot1<A1>::operator()(7)
Handling new value: 7
```

## Version 3 Output (Visual Studio 2010)

```
Signal1<A1>::raise(7)
Slot::operator()(7)
Slot1<A1>::operator()(7)
Handling new value: 7
```

## Code

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Version 1: uses perfect forwarding with std::function<void (T)>
// Version 2: uses perfect forwarding with std::function<void (const T&)>
// Version 3: forgoes perfect forwarding with std::function<void (T)>

#define VER 1

class Slot
{
public:
    template<typename A1>
#if VER == 1 || VER == 2
    void operator()(A1&& a1) const;
#elif VER == 3
    void operator()(A1 a1) const;
#endif
};

template<typename A1>
class Slot1 : public Slot
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Slot1(T* instance, void (T::*fn)(A1)) :
        mFn(std::bind(fn, instance, std::placeholders::_1))
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    void operator()(A1 a1) const
    {
        std::cout << "Slot1<A1>::operator()(" << a1 << ")\n";
        mFn(a1);
    }

private:
#if VER == 1 || VER == 3
    std::function<void (A1)> mFn;
#elif VER == 2
    std::function<void (const A1&)> mFn;
#endif
};

template<typename A1>
#if VER == 1 || VER == 2
void Slot::operator()(A1&& a1) const
#elif VER == 3
void Slot::operator()(A1 a1) const
#endif
{
    std::cout << "Slot::operator()(" << a1 << ")\n";
#if VER == 1 || VER == 2
    static_cast<const Slot1<A1>&>(*this)(std::forward<A1>(a1));
#elif VER == 3
    static_cast<const Slot1<A1>&>(*this)(a1);
#endif
}

class Signal
{
public:
    void connect(Slot* slot)
    {
        mSlots.push_back(slot);
    }

    std::vector<Slot*> mSlots;
};

template<typename A1>
class Signal1 : public Signal
{
public:
    void raise(A1 a1)
    {
        std::cout << "Signal1<A1>::raise(" << a1 << ")\n";
        (*mSlots[0])(a1);
    }
};

class Model
{
public:
    void setValue(int value)
    {
        mValue = value;
        mValueChangedSignal.raise(value);
    }

    Signal1<int> mValueChangedSignal;

private:
    int mValue;
};

class View
{
public:
    void handleChange(int value)
    {
        std::cout << "Handling new value: " << value << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    View view;

    Slot1<int> slot(&view, &View::handleChange);

    Signal1<int> signal;
    signal.connect(&slot);

    signal.raise(7);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Is this a Visual Studio bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Stupid question: does VS2010 claim full support for C++11?

Comment: @Jeff There are numerous C++11 features which are not available but I didn't see anything on the C++ support page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh567368.aspx) which was obviously related to this (e.g., `std::function`, perfect forwarding)

Comment: Version 1 works correctly with VS2015 RC.

Comment: @R2-Dequeue Thanks, I'll also test with 2013 once I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1 and 2 do undefined behavior, as `Slot::operator()` of `Slot1<int>` is called with `A1` equal to `int&` within `Signal1<int>`, which then `static_cast`s itself to `Slot1<int&>`.  It is not a `Slot1<int&>`, so that cast generates a bad reference, which you then use, and boom, whatever happens happens.

Please check your types and stop explicit casting based of parameter types, that is ridiculously unsafe and annoying to track down.

I am uninterested in untangling the mess of `#ifdef`s in your code to determine if a similar error occurs with version 3.  Your design is fundamentally unsafe, as relatively innocuous argument changes within argument passing to `Slot` cause undefined behavior.  You should not be implicitly taking deduced parameters to `operator()` and using it to cast the type of `this` to a derived type.

Treat type casting with respect.

Here is a detailed breakdown of the undefined behavior your code causes in case 1:

```
signal.raise(7);
```

calls

```
Signal1<int>::raise(int)
```

which calls

```
void raise(int a1)
{
    (*mSlots[0])(a1);
}
```

here `a1` is an lvalue of type `int`.  So this calls

Slot::operator()(int& a1) const
because that is how forwarding references work -- `T&&` passed an `int&` deduces `T` as `int&`.  The body then contains

```
static_cast<const Slot1<int&>&>(*this)(std::forward<int&>(a1));
```

which casts `*this` into a reference to `Slot1<int&>`, a class that is unrelated to the object in question.  Undefined behavior results when you try to interact with it.

As I have said, fixing this is possible, but your fundamental problem is that the deduction of the type parameter in `Slot::operator()` is **not a suitable way** to determine what sub-type of `Slot` you want to cast `*this` into.  The type of an expression passed to `operator()` is not, in general, obvious at point of call, nor at point of deduction.  And if you do not get this type **exactly** right, the result is undefined behavior.  Which can often "seem to work", until some completely unrelated change occurs and it breaks.

When casting to-derived from-base, you must must must be careful, explicit, and document what you are doing at every step.

If someone calls your `Slot` (which is actually a `Slot1<int>`) with an unsigned int, undefined behavior.  A size_t, undefined behavior.  A unsigned char, undefined behavior.  A uint16_t, undefined behavior.  Adds a long long to an unsigned int, calls you with result, undefined behavior.  A type that implicitly converts to int, undefined behavior.

polymorphism without type safety is rarely a good idea.

On top of this, there is no good reason in your code to do this.  `Signal1<A1>` could implement `connect` instead of `Signal` taking a `Slot1<A1>` -- you, after all, have the type right there -- and store an array of `Slot1<A1>` instead of an array of `Slot`.  Given that **the only type of `Slot` that would not result in undefined behavior later on is a `Slot1<A1>`**, why store the wrong type at all?

Comment: To be clear, I am only interested in understanding the code path associated with version 1. I am genuinely interested if knowing if I've done something wrong but you state `Signal1<int>` casts itself to `Slot1<int&>` but the there is not cast in `Signal1<int>`. The cast is in the base `Slot` class. Therefore, the slot class instance is actually a `Slot1<int>`, correct?

Comment: The only reason I have version 2 and 3 is because I was trying to see what edits I could make to get the code to behave the way I expected.

Comment: `static_cast<const Slot1<A1>&>(*this)(std::forward<A1>(a1));` casts a `Slot` to a `Slot1<int&>` when `Slot::operator()` is called from one of your signal classes.  This can be fixed: Regardless your code is fundamentally unsafe.  Dangerous casts (like that static cast to derived in `Slot::operator()`) should not be done based off function argument type deduction of an `operator()`.  Using operator() in a way that is completely type-unsafe makes broken code difficult to avoid and spot.

Comment: And no, your first comment is not what I stated.  Yes my paragraph is difficult to read: but that reflects the structure of the code I'm describing.  The signal calls the slot, which deduces a template type parameter, which is `int&`, which induces a cast, which is wrong.  The type of `A1` is `int&`, not `int`, within version1, within `Slot::operator()`.  Please do not use `operator()` in the way you are using it.

Comment: Okay, I reread that comment and now I think I understand what you were saying.

Comment: "Dangerous casts (like that static cast to derived in Slot::operator()) should not be done based off function argument type deduction of an operator()."  I have a question related to this. I'm trying to experiment with how I can have a non-templated base type but have the implementation in the templated class. Is there an idiom for this? In this case, I couldn't make a virtual function because the base class can't have a templated virtual function.

Comment: "casts a `Slot` to a `Slot1<int&>`". Could you explain why this is the case (possibly in your answer)? I would have expected it to be casting `Slot` to a `Slot1<int>` (not `Slot1<int&>`).

Comment: I brushed up on `std::forward` and see why it's `int&` instead of `int`. Furthermore, I explicitly performed `static_cast<const Slot1<int>&>` (only to test the `int&` vs `int` thing) instead of `static_cast<const Slot1<A1>&>` and the the code started working. Thank you for taking your time to track down what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @JamesAdkison be aware that when dealing with undefined behavior, "it started working" is not strong evidence that your code is correct.  And incorrect code can break in the next compiler revision, a different optimization setting, or because the phase of the moon (aka seemingly unrelated changes elsewhere).  The downcast from base to derived is *dangerous*, and you must be *absolutely certain* you get it right, or you are in for a world of pain: It must be hard for you to get it wrong.  If it isn't hard, you should reconsider your design entirely.

Comment: Yes, I didn't like it before and now that I more fully understand the complexities of this situation I believe it is not a viable solution. I will "go back to the drawing board" to find a better solution. Just in case you missed it the first time. Previously I asked, Is there a idiom for having a non-templated base class with templated derived classes?

Comment: @JamesAdkison Not really?  It is sort of like upside down CRTP, without the type-safety.  You don't have any different state in the derived classes in your case, I don't see a need for them to exist?  And if you do have different state, it makes it even more dangerous.  I seem to be missing the good reason why `Slot` and `Signal` without the signature of the message they pass need to exist at all: when I write messaging frameworks, my slot/signals have signatures.

Comment: I think you're suggestion to store pointers to the actual slot type (e.g., `Slot1<A1>*`) in the derived signal classes instead of the base `Slot*` class will have the benefit of working correctly and avoid having to get from the base `Slot` class to the derived slot classes (i.e., remove the need for that casting). The only reason I originally thought to store it in the base class was to avoid doing it in all the derived class but since that obviously isn't working....

Comment: "It must be hard for you to get it wrong. If it isn't hard, you should reconsider your design entirely." I agree completely, It was just my lack of understanding that didn't allow me to see that I was going down a road that was "hard to get right". I will reevaluate the need for the base classes (they currently cannot be instantiated) but I was going to use them to allow either to disconnect from the other when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86626/discussion-between-james-adkison-and-yakk).